# Python Socket only returns Response header instead of HTML

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I want to extract links from a website js. Using sockets, I'm trying to get the web JS but it always shows response header and not an actual JS/HTML. Here's what I'm using:

```
import socket
import ssl

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cont = ssl.create_default_context()
sock.connect(('blog.clova.line.me', 443))
sock = cont.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname = 'blog.clova.line.me')
sock.sendall('GET /hs/hsstatic/HubspotToolsMenu/static-1.138/js/index.js HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: blog.clova.line.me\r\n\r\n'.encode())
resp = sock.recv(2048)
print(resp.decode('utf-8'))
```

It returns only response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 06 Sep 2022 12:02:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
CF-Ray: 74670e8b9b594c2f-SIN
Age: 3444278
...
```

I have tried the following:

1. Setting `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` header
2. Changing the header to `GET https://blog.clova.line.me/hs/hsstatic/HubspotToolsMenu/static-1.138/js/index.js HTTP/1.1`

Have been searching related, it's seems that: other people is able to achieve HTML data after response header are received, but for me; I only able to receive the headers and not the HTML data. Frankly, it's working on `requests`:

```
resp = requests.get('https://blog.clova.line.me/hs/hsstatic/HubspotToolsMenu/static-1.138/js/index.js')
print(resp.text)
```

How can I achieve similar result using `socket`? Honestly, I don't like using 3rd-party module that's why I'm not using `requests`.

Comment: With a stream protocol such as TCP, a single call to `.recv()` does not return any particular amount of data - the parameter you pass is a maximum, not a minimum.  It's quite possible that the web server has a slight pause between emitting the headers and emitting the actual page contents, so receiving only the headers on the first call isn't unexpected.  You need to keep calling `.recv()` until the entire content has been received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response is just truncated: `sock.recv(2048)` is reading just the first 2048 bytes. If you read more bytes, you will see the body after the headers.

Anyway, I wouldn't recommend doing that using such a low level library.

> Honestly, I don't like
> using 3rd-party module that's why I'm not using `requests`.

If your point is to stick to the python standard library, you can use [`urrlib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) which provides more abstraction than `socket`:

```
import urllib
req = urllib.request.urlopen('…')
print(req.read())
```

Comment: Perfect and surprisingly close to what ```requests``` does.

Comment: Good suggestion but it didn't answer the OP's main question. *why* his/her code didn't work ?

Comment: @Xav Don't you interested in what did you do wrong or what was your problem ?

Comment: @S.B the response is just truncated: `sock.recv(2048)` is reading just the first 2048 bytes. If you read more bytes, you will see the body after the headers.

Comment: @etuardu So please edit your answer and include that too.

Comment: I do interested in the problem, infact; I'm still debugging my code and adding more headers and ssl cipher. This answer served as my main option incase ```socket``` keep failing @S.B

Comment: No, it wasn't because of ```sock.recv()```, even I have tried to raise it to unhealthy amount 10.000; still wasn't giving me the ```html``` body. As you can see from this: https://imgur.com/ef0Vpw8 @etuardu

Comment: @Xav: it seems you cannot read all at once, but if you put a `while True:` before your `sock.recv` call, so that receiving from the network and printing the buffer is looped indefinitely, you will see the whole content printed.

Comment: That's fixed the problem, but why it reads separately; i mean, is it possible to print only the body without involving additional step? Also, you need to include this in your answer, Thanks a lot.. https://imgur.com/a/VdPC2v5 @etuardu

Comment: Well, that's why it's not recommended to use `socket` for such a task. With `socket` you are working withing the TCP layer. Here you just see a stream of bytes. There is no awareness about what headers or the body are, or even about the content length: those features belongs to the upper HTTP layer. `urllib` works at such level and does the job for you. The `while True` trick is just a proof of concept and not a solution, you would need a far amount of code to do it properly.

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket):

> Now we come to the major stumbling block of sockets - send and recv
> operate on the network buffers. They do not necessarily handle all the
> bytes you hand them (or expect from them), because their major focus
> is handling the network buffers. In general, they return when the
> associated network buffers have been filled (send) or emptied (recv).
> They then tell you how many bytes they handled. **It is your
> responsibility to call them again until your message has been
> completely dealt with.**

I've re-write your code and added a `receive_all` function, which handles the received bytes: (Of course it's a naive implementation)

```py
import socket
import ssl

request_text = (
    "GET /hs/hsstatic/HubspotToolsMenu/static-1.138/js/index.js "
    "HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: blog.clova.line.me\r\n\r\n"
)

host_name = "blog.clova.line.me"


def receive_all(sock):
    chunks: list[bytes] = []
    while True:
        chunk = sock.recv(2048)
        if not chunk.endswith(b"0\r\n\r\n"):
            chunks.append(chunk)
        else:
            break
    return b"".join(chunks)



cont = ssl.create_default_context()
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.settimeout(5)
    with cont.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=host_name) as ssock:
        ssock.connect((host_name, 443))
        ssock.sendall(request_text.encode())

        resp = receive_all(ssock)
        print(resp.decode("utf-8"))
```